# Is possible to route with gunicorn to different endpoint to specific CPU?

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I have a endpoint that take a long time to answer. Is just one. I wonder if is possible to route something like:

```
Url(/costly) -> Worker 1
Url(/all) -> Worker 2-4
```

So my main site not get slow when the `/costly` endpoint is called.

P.D: I run it on docker. I could duplicate the web app and redirect with nginx, but think is wastefull. I now I could use a queue but this requiere a rearchitect of the app and need a stopgap by now..

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) to create an  asynctask in `/costly` is much better than  play with the workers in gunicorn

Comment: Because it requiere a massive change to everything and need a stop-gap solution.